# Sublime 3 and eclipse like Content Assist for Rust

Tags: eclipse, sublimetext, sublimetext3, rust, content-assist

Due to lack of Rust IDE, I am forced to use Sublime 3 with Rust plugin which I find really useful anyway. I was wondering how to improve learning curve with Rust. Does sublime have eclipse like Content Assist for Rust std? Is there an easy way to browse Rust std without going to the Internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually have a local build of Rust with docs  (they come with the tar file, too). `rustdoc` is pretty easy to navigate.

However, glennw's [RustAutoComplete](https://github.com/glennw/RustAutoComplete) plugin using the RACER tool gives you decent stdlib completion within Sublime Text.

Comment: RustAutoComplete with RACER is pretty neat. Since the original was posted a lot of work was done. It now auto completes a lot more than just the standard library and offers things like "jump to definition".